# Average of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure there is a super simple answer to this...

I have a dataframe like below:

The simulation is run 3 times for 4 time steps t. At each time step, a task (0,1,2) is chosen.

I want to find out the % of times that task 1 is chosen averaged over the 3 simulations at each time step t. I'm sure its some sort of simple groupby().mean() but i can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated!

| t | simulation | chosen_task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: how the expected output should look like?

Comment: A dataframe of length 4 (t=0,1,2,3) with a column which is % likelyhood that chosen_task 1 was selected. i.e. first row would be 0.33 (as at time step 0 for each simulation chosen_task 1 was selected 1/3 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` to calculate the *normalized counts* of `chosen_task` for each time step

```
pd.crosstab(df['t'], df['chosen_task'], normalize='index')[1]
```

---

```
t
0    0.333333
1    0.666667
2    0.333333
3    0.666667
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```